# Is there a less awkward way to store a value in a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

I have a hash of hashes in Ruby to which I'm inserting new hashes or adding values to existing hashes.
I keep feeling like Ruby has a better way to do this:

```
map   # => { 1 => {:type => "humbug", :name => "grinch" }, 2 => {:type => 2 } }

  if map[key]
    map[key].store(:name, value)
  else
    map[key] = { name: value }
  end
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
map[key].store(:name, value) || map[key] = {name: value}
```

but of course that fails if there is no `value` at `map[key]`
... suggestions?

Comment: There is no "map" in Ruby, there are Hashes.

Comment: @meagar busted! I use groovy all day long... in which there are maps all over the place :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a less awkward way?

Yes.

```
map[key] ||= {}
map[key].store(:name, value) # or map[key][:name] = value
```

Or make use of one of Hash missing value handlers.

```
map = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} }
# then set fearlessly, missing hashes will be auto-created.
map[key][:name] = value
```

Comment: `(map[key] ||= {}).store(:name, value)`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Me, I wouldn't go this far. But to each his own :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would go that far.  I love Ruby's elegance.